# chrome extension: which page getBackgroundPage() retrieve?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am a little confused whether this api suits my need. I want a common place to view my logs, instead of going around to the popup's console, the background page's console, etc...

Then I noticed that you can include several background scripts. In which case, which page does the api give us?

Comment: The page is single and just like any other page it can load many scripts.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes, you are right. To do proper justice, please write answer with some pics proving the point...

Answer (score 1):

Chrome does not support multiple background pages in a chrome extension. It supports multiple background scripts. But it does not supports both background page and background scripts at the same time. See below the screenshots.

> Error shown when we try add background page and script at the same
>   time.

[image]

> Error shown when we try add multiple background pages.

[image]

Now coming back to your question `which page getBackgroundPage() retrieve?`

Since chrome supports only one background page it will return the only page that you include in you manifest.json.